# Is it possible to use imagemagick as library reference from Adobe AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air, imagemagick, jpeg

I'm trying to load preview thumbnails of high resolution images and the application needs to be able to load 100 hi rez images at one time. The only way i know how to do this is if I use the Loader class and I have to load the ENTIRE file and then scale down the image and use the data as an image preview.

what i'd like to do is use imagemagick (or some other efficient image manipulation lib) to compress the image and return that result (without saving it as a file first... that would be optimal) back to my AIR application so that i can use it as a preview. This would be AWESOME.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommandProxy by Mike Chambers. Look it up (http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/). This nifty trick allows you to have a conversation between AIR and non-AIR apps.

Still have questions? Let us know.